# Receive notification when drawing of map is finished?

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, nsnotification

I'm using Google Maps iOS SDK for drawing a lot of markers on the map. As the drawing happens on the main thread, is it possible to receive a notification when the map view has finished drawing?

I'm using `SVProgressHUD` do display an activity indicator on the screen, but it disappears when the mapview starts drawing the markers.

Comment: There isn't any delegate methods for this, how are you adding all your markers? if your using a Array why not count to the last marker then remove loading indicator

Comment: I'm doing that already, but then the mapview needs 2-3 seconds to display the marker on the map.